# Files Encryption Java

Tags: java, security, encryption

I'm making a system that has some data in it, and I want it to take this data (in XML format) and save it as an encrypted string in a txt file, and later on when the software opens again, decrypt the file and read it as normal. I already have all the code to convert the xml to a string, I already have the code to save it, I just need some help with the encryption/decryption code?

Note: I did find some code to encrypt/decrypt, but it seems that I can't split the code into 2 methods.

Here is my attempt:

```
    public class AesEncrDec
{

public static String encrypt(String Data)
{
    byte[] byteCipherText = null;
    try {
        String plainData=Data,cipherText,decryptedText;
        KeyGenerator keyGen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
        keyGen.init(128);
        SecureRandom rnd = new SecureRandom();
        SecretKey secretKey = keyGen.generateKey();
        IvParameterSpec iv;
        iv = new IvParameterSpec(rnd.generateSeed(16));
        Cipher aesCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        aesCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE,secretKey,iv); 
        byte[] byteDataToEncrypt = plainData.getBytes();
        byteCipherText = aesCipher.doFinal(byteDataToEncrypt);
        cipherText = new BASE64Encoder().encode(byteCipherText);
        return new String(byteCipherText);
    } catch (InvalidKeyException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(AesEncrDec.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(AesEncrDec.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(AesEncrDec.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(AesEncrDec.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (BadPaddingException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(AesEncrDec.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(AesEncrDec.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return new String(byteCipherText);
}

public static String dencrypt(String Data)
{
    byte[] byteDecryptedText = null;
    try {
        KeyGenerator keyGen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
        keyGen.init(128);
        IvParameterSpec iv;
        SecureRandom rnd = new SecureRandom();
        iv = new IvParameterSpec(rnd.generateSeed(16));
        Cipher aesCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        SecretKey secretKey = keyGen.generateKey();
        aesCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE,secretKey,iv);
        byteDecryptedText = aesCipher.doFinal(Data.getBytes());
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(AesEncrDec.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(AesEncrDec.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InvalidKeyException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(AesEncrDec.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(AesEncrDec.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(AesEncrDec.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (BadPaddingException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(AesEncrDec.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return new String(byteDecryptedText);
}
}
```

EDIT : In responce to @Libin here are the errors

```
Mar 24, 2014 6:27:42 PM PrefsReadAndWrite.AesEncrDec decrypt
SEVERE: null
javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:966)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:824)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineDoFinal(AESCipher.java:436)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2121)
    at PrefsReadAndWrite.AesEncrDec.decrypt(AesEncrDec.java:61)
    at PrefsReadAndWrite.AesEncrDec.decryptedString(AesEncrDec.java:104)
    at smarthouse.SmartHouse.main(SmartHouse.java:12)

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:554)
    at PrefsReadAndWrite.AesEncrDec.decryptedString(AesEncrDec.java:105)
    at smarthouse.SmartHouse.main(SmartHouse.java:12)
Java Result: 1
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by _can't split the code_? P.S. seeing empty catch blocks makes most developer's skin crawl; **never ever do this**. Not even for fun.

Comment: `plainData.getBytes();` <-- DON'T DO THAT, especially not with XML. XML documents have their own encoding, use that information to generate the correct byte array.

Comment: @fge im actually trying to encrypt a String not and actual XML

Comment: Even in this case, specify the charset; the recipients' JRE/OS combo of this encrypted content may not use the same charset as your JRE/OS combo. If you don't know which to choose, choose `StandardCharsets.UTF_8`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to generate the key only once and use it for encrypt and decrypt.. Use this code ...

**AppSecurity class should be used to generate new key and Encrypt/Decrypt**

```
public class AppSecurity{
private AppSecurity() {}

public static byte[] encrypt(byte[] key , byte[] data) {
    SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
    try {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE,keySpec);
        return cipher.doFinal(data);
    }
    catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e){ }
    catch (NoSuchPaddingException e){ }
    catch (InvalidKeyException e){ }
    catch (BadPaddingException e){ }
    catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {}
    return null;
}

public static byte[] decrypt(byte[] key , byte[] encryptedData) {
    SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key ,"AES");
    try {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keySpec);
        return cipher.doFinal(encryptedData);
    }
    catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {}
    catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) { }
    catch (InvalidKeyException e) { }
    catch (BadPaddingException e) {}
    catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {}
    return null;
}

/**
 * method to generate a secure key. call this when app starts
 * @return
 */
public static byte[] generateKey(){
    try{
        // create an AES algorithm instance.
        KeyGenerator keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
        SecureRandom secureRandom = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
        keyGenerator.init(128,secureRandom);
        SecretKey secretKey = keyGenerator.generateKey();
        return secretKey.getEncoded();
    }
    catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e){
        return null;
    }
  }
}
```

Method to Encrypt the string.

```
 private static byte[] encryptedByte(String s) {
    return AppSecurity.encrypt(YourApplication.getSecretKey(),toBytes(s));
 }
```

Method to Decrypt the byte.

```
  private static String decryptedString(byte[] blob) {
    // here getSecretKey() should be the one used on encryption
    byte[] decrypted =  AppSecurity.decrypt(YourApplication.getSecretKey(),blob);
    return toString(decrypted);
```

}

Method to convert Byte to String

```
public static String toString(byte[] bytes) {
  try {
    String s = new String(bytes ,"UTF-8");
     return s;
     } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
      return null;
     }
  }
```

Method to convert String to Byte

```
 public static byte[] toBytes(String s) {
   try {
       return s.getBytes("UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {return null;}
   }
```

**Detail on how to use this in your application :**
initialize initSecurity() method on your application/applet class and store the return key into a variable and make use of this on runtime.

Assuming class name as **YourApplication.java**

```
 // initialize it on your app startup
 String mSecretKey = initSecurity()

 // call this method when you encrypt /decrypt
 public static byte[] getSecretKey() { return mSecretKey; }
```

//Add this method to read from file or generate one new key

```
 private void initSecurity() {
    final String secretFile = "secure_file";
    boolean keyExists = false;
    //check if secret key exist in secure file
    try {
        FileInputStream inputStream = openFileInput(secretFile);
        mSecretKey = new byte[16];
        int result = inputStream.read(mSecretKey);
        if(result >0) {
            keyExists = true;
        }
        inputStream.close();
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
    catch (IOException e){}
    if(!keyExists) {
        // generate a key
        mSecretKey = AppSecurity.generateKey();
        if(mSecretKey != null) {
            // write in a secure file inside the app
            try {
                // MODE_PRIVATE will create the file (or replace a file of the same name)
                // and make it private to the application.
                FileOutputStream outputStream = openFileOutput(secretFile,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                outputStream.write(mSecretKey);
                outputStream.close();
            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException e){}
            catch (IOException e) {}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: that runs with no errors but it returns null in both the encrypt and decrypt methods

Comment: See my updated answer. Call encryptedByte() to encrypt the string and use decryptedString() to decrypt the encrypted byte.

Comment: can you see what exception it throws?

Comment: Exception seems to be in decrypt. Are u using the same key used for encrypt ?

Comment: can you show an example of how should I call the methods and how can i print the encrypt and dencrypt values I'm not sure i'm calling them right.. sorry im sorta noob im programming

Comment: You have to store the getSecretKey() somewhere , I use to store in a file in android. and when the app start i will read from the file.If it doesn't exit in file then i will generate one. You have to keep hold of the generated or read key in your system on runtime.

Comment: ohh ok now i get it now thanks man sorry about my dumbness haha

Comment: Ok. good your clear now.. See my updated answer. I have added method initSecurity() to generate new one or read from file.

Comment: Ok. I did some cleanup in renaming the methods. Now all set :). It might help some one.

Comment: -1 for empty catch blocks. It should also be noted that you cannot just convert a `byte[]` of encrypted bytes into a `String`. The `byte[]` does not conform to any encoding. You have to use something like hex or base64 to store these bytes as a `String`.

Comment: @Boris It doesn't make any sence -1 for empty catch block. Its up to the developer who uses this code have to refactor as per his need.

Comment: Well then you should rethrow the exception. Because we both know the OP will copy paste the code in and not give it second thought. While you may be correct (is it up to the OP) answers should adhere to coding best practice. Code that doesn't compile shouldn't be an answer and this is just as bad.

Comment: @Boris I agree with Libin that unproper exception handling does not make an otherwise good answer worth downvoting. Why not just comment asking to alter this part?

Comment: @Drunix obviously I disagree. And if the post is edited I will remove my down vote. Further this post misses important points about how the OP handles the `byte[]` returned from encryption - i.e. the OP is converting it to a `String` using string's constructor. This is invalid and will not work as the `byte[]` is **not** a UTF-8 encoding string but (essentially) random data.

Comment: Ok, I can live with the fact that we will not reach an agreement on the badness of empty catch blocks in sample code. Storing the encryted data as a string is surely broken (I also mentioned that in my answer), but the answer fixes this point by returning byte[] instead of strings.

Answer (score 0):

You don't define the padding to be used, so an implementation defined padding is used. According to your error, this is probably "NoPadding" in your case. Specify padding and mode of operation, e.g. `AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding`. Since you now will be using CBC, you also need an initialization vector:

```
IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(rnd.generateSeed(16));
aesCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE,secretKey,iv);
```

where `rnd` is a `SecureRandom` instance. Also returning the data as String is a bad idea, use the bytes directly. And of course follow Libins advice to use the same key for encryption and decryption,.

Comment: I couldn't use the rnd.generateSeed(16) what function is that?

Comment: @erickson: Why did you change it to PKCS5? I know it works, but only because it is interpreted as pkcs#7 padding. PKCS5 is for 8 byte blocksize, while AES uses 16 byte blocks. Therefore I recommended PKCS#7 padding.

Comment: @Caio Petrelli: Use a SecureRandom object. Forgot to mention that, because they are so common in this field.

Comment: PKCS7Padding is not a standard name defined by JCA Standard Algorithm names, so some providers will raise `NoSuchAlgorithmException`. Providers that interpret PKCS5Padding as PKCS #7 padding when applied to blocks longer than 8 bytes are common.

Comment: @Drunix ive tryed to implement the code and it did not work still returns the same error, Im going to update the question take a look

Comment: @erickson: Ok, that's a valid reason. I didn't like to rely on this implicit reinterpretation.

Comment: Yes, it would be best if they would tighten up the documentation. PKCS1Padding is ambiguous too; every provider I've used, but one, interprets it as v. 1.5 (RSAES-PKCS1-V1_5). The other provider interprets it as v. 2.0 (RSAES-OAEP). What a pain.