# Java Decryption Returns Blank

Tags: java, encryption

I'm currently working on an encryption program, and I'm having an issue when decrypting. The resulting file is blank, and I have been trying to find the reason for this for about an hour. My decryption code is below...

Can someone please tell me why my data might come out blank?

```
                        file = x;
                        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file.getAbsolutePath());

                        file = new File(file.getAbsolutePath().substring(0,
                                file.getAbsolutePath().length() - 4));

                        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);

                        byte k[] = Hash.MD5(password).getBytes("UTF-8");
                        SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(k, "AES");

                        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(algorithm);

                        byte[] iv = batchIV;
                        IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);

                        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, ivSpec);
                        CipherInputStream cin = new CipherInputStream(fis,
                                cipher);

                        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                        int read = 0;

                        while ((read = cin.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                            fos.write(buffer, 0, read);
                        }

                        fos.flush();
                        fos.close();
                        cin.close();
```

Links go to larger code portions.

Decrypt Method Here: http://pastebin.com/2p2juUTa

Full Class Here: http://pastebin.com/hgZHT4wg

I've found that the CipherInputStream is returning -1 when you try to read from it... I'm still unsure as to what might cause this, if anyone can help.

Comment: check my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22619602/files-encryption-java/22620403#22620403

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't see how your answer applies to this. You're not using any Cipher Streams, while I am. I have a perfectly fine encryption method, however, the issue arises when decrypting, and I am unable to find why the CipherInputStream returns -1 when being read.

Comment: "My encryption code is below." No, your *decryption* code is below. Where's your encryption code? Are you sure you aren't producing zero-length files? or files with encryption headers but no data?

Comment: It was a typo. I will post the whole class in a second...

Comment: Full Class Here: http://pastebin.com/hgZHT4wg

Comment: Please reduce that to a [short self-contained compilable example](http://www.sscce.org/) and post it all here.

Comment: I'll update it with that tomorrow, as it is past midnight, however, I don't see why it's necessary if my issue is purely with the CipherInputStream.

Comment: So you assume, but if you were right about everything you wouldn't have a problem and you wouldn't be posting the question. I don't see anything wrong with your cipher code, but I can see several other problems, some of them in code you haven't even posted.

Comment: Fixed my own problem. I was pointing to the wrong file, which was feeding into the input stream. The joys of misplaced variables.

Comment: Also, @EJP, it was a problem with the cipher code. I was referring to my static File by mistake when passing it into the first stream.

Comment: I wouldn't call that a 'problem with your cipher code', just with your code. However your code worked for me when I made the corrections in my answer excluding changing the File from static.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't state what `Hash.MD5()` and `Hash.MD5R()` do, let alone supply the source code, but evidently `MD5()` returns a `String,` which is already an error (see below), and that `MD5R()` only returns the input argument, which is basically pointless. Unless you think you've discovered a way to reverse MD5? You haven't.

If you make the following changes to your code:

1. change `MD5()` to return the `byte[]` resulting from the `MessageDigest.digest()` operation that it must perform, instead of wrapping that in a String, and make the corresponding adjustments at the callings sites (i.e. remove `.toByteArray("UTF-8")` in a couple of places, and
2. change `MD5R()` to return the input argument, or just remove the method,

you will find that your code works.

NB:

1. Repeat after me: 'String is not a container for binary data'.
2. `flush()` before `close()` is redundant.
3. The `File` variable `file` should be method-local, not static.
4. You don't need all those `File.getAbsolutePath()` method calls. `getPath()` will work just as well in most cases, or just the `File` object itself in others.

Comment: It's already been solved, but I cannot close this for 8 hours. Also, I understand what you listed, however, I do have my reasons for using a static file variable, however, I referenced it in the wrong place, and that caused my whole issue. As for the strings holding binary data, that was a bandaid fix, as I was having a small issue, and wanted to get the important part of the code up and running.

The other two points make sense, however, with flushing first, I've learned that it's good practice. I've had bad experiences with not doing it before, with other types of streams.